# SQL*Plus @@ behaviour with spaces in the parent script path

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have to

1. Connect
2. Call sql-script
3. Exit sqlplus

So, I've created a sql-script run.sql:

```
set def on
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK
conn &2
@"&1";

exit;
```

For example, I have some sql-scripts in a folder "c:\folder with spaces\":

a) install.sql with contents:

```
prompt Hello
@@a.sql
@@b.sql
```

b) and of course I have a.sql and b.sql files in the folder with some actions.

So, I try to run my script:

```
sqlplus /nolog @"Path_to_Run\run.sql" \"c:\folder with spaces\install.sql\" user/pass@server
```

And I got an output:

```
Hello
SP2-0310: unable to open file "c:\folder.sql"
```

So, it can open install.sql, but cannot open @@a.sql. He tries to run such script:

```
@c:\folder with spaces\a.sql
```

But how can I place quotes here? He should run the script a.sql inside the folder "c:\folder with spaces\".

Comment: If you have access, see MOS document 745780.1 which describes this behaviour. You need a workaround unfortunately, like the one StephaneM provides.

Comment: There is a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alex Poole, the answer is in documentation

> SP2-0310 Error when Calling a SQL Script in Another Script using @@ and the Path to the Parent Script Contains Spaces (Doc ID 745780.1)

And there are three solutions:

1. Use the 8dot3 notation. E.g. Use PROGRA~1 instead of "Program Files".
2. Avoid saving the sql scripts on a path containing spaces in the folder names.
3. cd to the directory containing the script instead of providing the full path when invoking the script in SQL*Plus.

First method doesn't work for me in Windows 7 (there are a lot of work to set up 8dot3 in Win7). I get:

```
>cd c:\folder~1
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Second method doesn't work for me too, I cannot operate these folders. I have to use them as is.

And the third method works fine (but in another way than in the previous message):

```
cd "c:\folder with spaces"
sqlplus /nolog @c:\run\run.sql install.sql user/pass@server
```

So, you have to change dir before sqlplus, *host cd* doesn't work.

Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 1):

You could split your parameters so that run.sql contains

```
set def on
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK
conn &2
host cd "@3"
@"&1";

exit;
```

And invoke it with

```
sqlplus /nolog @"Path_to_Run\run.sql" \"c:\folder with spaces\" install.sql user/pass@server
```

Note that it might need some tuning, it does not work on my computer because of cygwin messing with its own cd.

Comment: This also doesn't work. I've added another line "_host cd_" below "_host cd "&1"_" to read the current path and what do I see? I see: _c:\run_, so I get error: unable to open file "install.sql"